# Sanity Studio v3 sanity.cli.js: What should the dataset value be when I have multiple environments?

Tags: sanity

I have recently upgraded to Sanity Studio 3 from version 2, and I find that I am a bit confused on what I should do with the dataset property in the `sanity.cli.js` file. This is the [minimal example from the docs](https://www.sanity.io/docs/cli#655678908474):

```
// sanity.cli.js
import { defineCliConfig } from "sanity/cli";

export default defineCliConfig({
  api: {
    projectId: "<your-project-id>",
    dataset: "production",
  }
});
```

Here, the `dataset` is hard coded to `production`. Am I supposed to hard code it to prod, or will it need to be read from the environment variables if we have multiple datasets? We have two, `dev` and `production` at the moment. If I hard code it to production, I am afraid to indadvertedly break something in prod when running a command via the cli, but that fear might be overblown.